# Mic and webcam not working in Acer Aspire ES-13 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: acer, aspire

my name is Ida, I'm from Chile and this is my first time using Linux/Ubuntu.

I need help with my webcam and microphone. I don't know how to install the proper drivers. Audio works fine with phones and speakers (for playing music).
I tried mic in audacity and google call, webcam is no available in google hangout.

a found a guide to use my terminal and see what my hardware is (lshw):

```
    *-usb
         descripción: USB controller
         producto: Intel Corporation

          *-usb:0
               descripción: Vídeo
               producto: VGA Webcam
               fabricante: NC2141102N60806C16LM21
               id físico: 3
               información del bus: usb@1:3
               versión: 3.21
               serie: 200901010001
               capacidades: usb-2.00
               configuración: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               descripción: Interfaz Bluetooth
               fabricante: Lite-On Technology Corp.
               id físico: 5
               información del bus: usb@1:5
               versión: 0.02
               capacidades: bluetooth usb-1.10
               configuración: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            producto: xHCI Host Controller
            fabricante: Linux 4.10.0-35-generic xhci-hcd
            id físico: 1
            información del bus: usb@2
            nombre lógico: usb2
            versión: 4.10
            capacidades: usb-3.00
            configuración: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
    *-generic
         descripción: Encryption controller
         producto: Intel Corporation
         fabricante: Intel Corporation
         id físico: 1a
         información del bus: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         versión: 35
         anchura: 32 bits
         reloj: 33MHz
         capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuración: driver=mei_txe latency=0
         recursos: irq:312 memoria:91300000-913fffff memoria:91200000-912fffff
    *-multimedia
         descripción: Audio device
         producto: Intel Corporation
         fabricante: Intel Corporation
         id físico: 1b
         información del bus: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         versión: 35
         anchura: 64 bits
         reloj: 33MHz
         capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuración: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         recursos: irq:311 memoria:91410000-91413fff
    *-pci:0
         descripción: PCI bridge
         producto: Intel Corporation
         fabricante: Intel Corporation
         id físico: 1c
         información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         versión: 35
         anchura: 32 bits
         reloj: 33MHz
         capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuración: driver=pcieport
         recursos: irq:16 ioport:1000(size=4096) memoria:91100000-911fffff ioport:91500000(size=2097152)
       *-generic
            descripción: Unassigned class
            producto: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            id físico: 0
            información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
            versión: 01
            anchura: 32 bits
            reloj: 33MHz
            capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom
            configuración: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
            recursos: irq:307 memoria:91105000-91105fff memoria:91110000-9111ffff
       *-network
            descripción: Ethernet interface
            producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            id físico: 0.1
            información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.1
            nombre lógico: enp1s0f1
            versión: 12
            serie: 30:65:ec:a4:7d:dd
            tamaño: 10Mbit/s
            capacidad: 1Gbit/s
            anchura: 64 bits
            reloj: 33MHz
            capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            recursos: irq:309 ioport:1000(size=256) memoria:91104000-91104fff memoria:91100000-91103fff
    *-pci:1
         descripción: PCI bridge
         producto: Intel Corporation
         fabricante: Intel Corporation
         id físico: 1c.1
         información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         versión: 35
         anchura: 32 bits
         reloj: 33MHz
         capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuración: driver=pcieport
         recursos: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=4096) memoria:91000000-910fffff ioport:91700000(size=2097152)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment because my rep, but have you tried the built in software cheese? (in spanish Fotomatón de camara web cheese). Maybe that will show you if it really isn't installed after all.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers. And even as a comment is irrelevant, the webcam is recognized and using the correct driver.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it was relevant to me: i didn't notice and tried with the web cheese, camera works, also for google, but mic does not work at all, Audacity and Google Hangout aswell as the sound configuration at the corner does not show activity at all.

Comment: Have you checked if in Sound->Input you have listed any devices? If so, you should check the audio levels for that device.

Comment: yes, "Micrófono, audio interno" it means "microphone, internal audio" it does not responde to any noise or sound. Levels are good for reproducing sound, but nothing is going on with the mic, even if I move the recording levels.